# Apply a lens "setter" only when the input value is a "Just x"?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Is there any way to apply the combinators/setters mentioned at [Control-Lens-Setter.html#g:4](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#g:4) when the **input value** (*not* the field being set), is a `Just x`?

For example, considering the `(~+)` combinator, if I have the following:

```
let target = (1, 2)
    input1 = Just 10
    input2 = Nothing
```

I want a setter that does the following:

```
(11, 2) == target & (_1 . someSetter) +~ input1 
                  & (_2 . someSetter) +~ input2
```

I'm trying to avoid using `fmap` or `maybe/fromMaybe` in this case, because I have a lot of such operations to do, and would prefer avoiding the boilerplate by leveraging the terseness/conciseness of lenses.

Answer (score 5):

You could always define your own setter.

```hs
maybeSetter :: (b -> a -> a) -> ASetter s t a a -> Maybe b -> s -> t
maybeSetter g f x = runIdentity . f (Identity . maybe id g x)

(+!) :: Num a => ASetter s t a a -> Maybe a -> s -> t
(+!) = maybeSetter (+)

let target = (1, 2)
    input1 = Just 10
    input2 = Nothing
in
    (11, 2) == target & (_1 . someSetter) +! input1 
                      & (_2 . someSetter) +! input2
```

You can also define other setters easily.

```hs
(-!) :: Num a => ASetter s t a a -> Maybe a -> s -> t
(-!) = maybeSetter subtract

(||!) :: ASetter s t Bool Bool -> Maybe Bool -> s -> t
(||!) = maybeSetter (||)

(<>!) :: Semigroup a => ASetter s t a a -> Maybe a -> s -> t
(<>!) = maybeSetter (flip (<>))

(.!) :: ASetter s t a a -> Maybe a -> s -> t
(.!) = maybeSetter const

(%!) :: ASetter s t a a -> Maybe (a -> a) -> s -> t
(%!) = maybeSetter id
```

That's the cool thing about lenses. They are just regular functions.

Comment: Hmm, does this force me to define a new setter for every setter in Control.Lens that I want to use, eg. `+~`, `-~`, `||~`, `<>~`, `.~`, `%~`, etc? I would be surprised that Control.Lens, being the ultimate swiss-army knife that it is, doesn't have something like this out of the box.

Comment: Yes, yes you would. However, it's not as bad as it seems. You can create a generic setter combinator and specialize it. For example, `maybeSetter :: (a -> a -> a) -> ASetter s t a a -> Maybe a -> s -> t; maybeSetter g f x = runIdentity . f (Identity . maybe id g x)`. Then, you can create specific functions like `(+!) = maybeSetter (+)`, `(-!) = maybeSetter subtract`, `(||!) = maybeSetter (||)`, `(<>!) = maybeSetter (flip (<>))`, `(.!) = maybeSetter const`, and `(%!) = maybeSetter id`. Note that this code is untested because I'm typing it on my phone.